# Setting a loop range with video.js

Tags: video.js

Is there a way to define a section of a video to loop with video.js?  I'd like to have some sort of range control with a start and end thumb and then have the selected range loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `timeupdate` event to check the video's `currentTime` to create a basic loop, as in the example below (see live at https://jsfiddle.net/o32bku6x/)

See also [loop a html5 video in specific timline with js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772699/loop-a-html5-video-in-specific-timline-with-js/41123610) .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.6.0/video.js"></script>
        <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.6.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    </head>
    <body>

        <video id="vid" controls="controls" class="video-js">
            <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        Start: <input type="text" size="5" id="loopStart" value="10" />
        End:   <input type="text" size="5" id="loopEnd"   value="15" />
        Loop:  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="loopEnabled" />

        <script>            
            var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
            vid.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate, false);

            function timeupdate() {
                var loopStart = parseFloat(document.getElementById('loopStart').value);
                var loopEnd = parseFloat(document.getElementById('loopEnd').value);
                var loopEnabled = document.getElementById('loopEnabled').checked;
                
                if(loopEnabled){
                    if (vid.currentTime < loopStart || vid.currentTime >= loopEnd ) {
                        vid.currentTime = loopStart;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could use a plugin such as https://github.com/phhu/videojs-abloop, which adds loop controls to the player. See example at https://unpkg.com/videojs-abloop/sample/basic.html (disclaimer: I wrote this plugin)

Comment: Thanks. It's close but there are a couple of errors. I've posted another answer. If you implement my suggestions in your answer, then I'll delete my answer. It was too much to put in a comment.

Comment: However... I just realized, - that if this is done, then it will download a new video every time the loop is played (itstead of downloading it once and playing that bit again and again). So it's quite data heavy. And I can see that your link videojs-abloop has accounted for that. So great link-suggestion! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make the same thing. @phhu was close, - but there are a couple of errors in his/her suggestion.

It worked, when I adjusted the script to be this:

```
<script>            
    videojs('vid').ready(function () {
    this.on('timeupdate', onVideoTimeupdate );
  });
  
  function onVideoTimeupdate() {
    var loopStart = parseFloat(document.getElementById('loopStart').value);
    var loopEnd = parseFloat(document.getElementById('loopEnd').value);
    var loopEnabled = document.getElementById('loopEnabled').checked;

    if(loopEnabled){
      if (this.currentTime() < loopStart || this.currentTime() >= loopEnd ) {
        this.currentTime( loopStart );
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

---

**Update**

A good comment (and Fiddle) from Phhu made me notice an error.

Here is a working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLf7s15j/

I've updated the code as well.
The problem was the [initialization of the video-js element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126826/1766219).

Comment: I couldn't get this to work using JS alone... JS fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/en8vt2dk/  gives "Uncaught TypeError: vid.on is not a function" Perhaps another library involved?

Comment: Good comment and thanks for the Fiddle. I've corrected the mistake and included a working Fiddle.