# loop a html5 video in specific timline with js

Tags: javascript, html, video

i had a html5 video box with only one video inside. in this video their is a animated figure with different moves. as an example: second 1-5 the figure walks inside, second 5-7 the figure say "hello", ... i would like to control these animations with js and i would like to loop the main animation.

this is the html5 videoplayer:

```
<video id="vidplayer">
<source src="animation.mp4" type="video/mp4"</source>
</video>
```

i have tested following code to loop the video between the second 7-9 and it doesnt work:

```
var vid = $("#vidplayer").get(0);

vid.ontimeupdate = function(e) {
    if(this.currentTime = 9) {
        vid.currentTime = 7;
        }
    };
```

it works only with

```
(this.currentTime >= 9)
```

but with this ">=" i cant use animations above 9 seconds (like 21-29 seconds).

can you please help me? Thx!

Comment: how about using nested if's... test for the highest time first eg if this.CurrentTime >= 29 blah else if currentTime >= 9 etc

Comment: thx for you answer. I tested it, but in doesnt. the player stops only on the lowest time.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to check for both the start/stop of the fragments you want to loop within in order to constrain the test.

In the example below it will loop from the 15s mark (or greater) back to 10s; from the 9s mark back to 7; from the 5s mark back to 1.

For a production version I'd probably create an array of the jump points and use that to avoid having to type the times as an upper/lower, but this should give you a framework to go on from:

```
<video preload="auto" controls id="vidplayer">  
<source src="BigBuck.m4v" type='video/mp4;'"></source></video>

<script>

var vid = document.getElementById("vidplayer")

vid.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate, false);

function timeupdate() {
    if (vid.currentTime >= 15) {
        vid.currentTime = 10;
    } else if (vid.currentTime >= 9 && vid.currentTime < 10) {
        vid.currentTime = 7;
    } else if (vid.currentTime >= 5 && vid.currentTime < 7) {
        vid.currentTime = 1;
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and wrote a plugin to solve it. See https://github.com/phhu/videojs-abloop . This allows javascript commands to be used to control looping of section of video. The example shows how you might control switching different sections of video using callbacks or otherwise.